# What happens with annotations when new node is created?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I got an answer to my question on where my annotation has gone ([Where is my annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734238/where-is-my-annotation)), and I've re-read it like 20 times, but I am still unclear why is this code not working, why I cannot get annotated property, where is the problem.  I've inlined the code so that is easier to read...

```
SyntaxAnnotation propertyAnnotation = null;
SyntaxAnnotation classAnnotation = null;

//first annotate class
classAnnotation = new SyntaxAnnotation();

var newRoot = document.GetSyntaxRoot()
                .ReplaceNode(classDeclaration, classDeclaration.WithAdditionalAnnotations(classAnnotation));

document = document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(newRoot);

//now annotate property 
//first look for classNode that was annotated in previous step
var classNode = document.GetAnnotatedNode<ClassDeclarationSyntax>(classAnnotation);

//now annotate property
propertyAnnotation = new SyntaxAnnotation();
var newClassNode = classNode.ReplaceNode(propertyDeclaration, propertyDeclaration.WithAdditionalAnnotations(propertyAnnotation));

newRoot = document.GetSyntaxRoot()
                     .ReplaceNode(classNode, newClassNode);

document = document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(newRoot);

//Works 
newClassNode = document.GetAnnotatedNode<ClassDeclarationSyntax>(classAnnotation);

//Fails here????
var newPropertyNode = document.GetAnnotatedNode<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>(propertyAnnotation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
var newClassNode = classNode.ReplaceNode(propertyDeclaration, propertyDeclaration.WithAdditionalAnnotations(propertyAnnotation));
```

Because you have annotated the class declaration, you will never find `propertyDeclaration` in that call.  It is part of the tree that has the original `classDeclaration`, not the annotated one.  You should re-find the `propertyDeclaration` after adding the annotation to `classDeclaration`.